# why write() doesn't return 0 when it should?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, broken-pipe

I've encountered a case where using `write()` server-side on a remotely closed client doesn't return 0.

According to man 2 `write` :

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates
>   nothing was written).  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately.

From my understanding: when using `read`/`write` on a remotely closed socket, the first attempt is supposed to fail (thus return `0`), and the next try should trigger a broken pipe. But it doesn't. `write()` acts as if it succeeded in sending the data on the first attempt, and then i get a broken pipe on the next try.

My question is why?

I know how to handle a broken pipe properly, that's not the issue. I'm just trying to understand why `write` doesn't return `0` in this case.

Below is the server code I wrote. Client-side, I tried a basic C client (with close() and shutdown() for closing the socket) and netcat. All three gave me the same result.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MY_STR "hello world!"

int start_server(int port)
{
  int fd;
  struct sockaddr_in sin;

  fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      perror(NULL);
      return (-1);
    }
  memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port = htons(port);
  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1
      || listen(fd, 0) == -1)
    {
      perror(NULL);
      close(fd);
      return (-1);
    }
  return (fd);
}

int accept_client(int fd)
{
  int client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in client_sin;
  socklen_t client_addrlen;

  client_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  client_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_sin, &client_addrlen);
  if (client_fd == -1)
    return (-1);
  return (client_fd);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd, fd_client;
  int port;
  int ret;

  port = 1234;
  if (argc == 2)
    port = atoi(argv[1]);
  fd = start_server(port);
  if (fd == -1)
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
  printf("Server listening on port %d\n", port);
  fd_client = accept_client(fd);
  if (fd_client == -1)
    {
      close(fd);
      printf("Failed to accept a client\n");
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  printf("Client connected!\n");
  while (1)
    {
      getchar();
      ret = write(fd_client, MY_STR, strlen(MY_STR));
      printf("%d\n", ret);
      if (ret < 1)
    break ;
    }
  printf("the end.\n");
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Note that you should also consider the fact that `write()` may return a number which is greater than 0 but less than `strlen(MY_STR)`, and it may also return -1 and signal `EINTR`.

Comment: In a code that's meant for production I would. The above code was written just to mess with write() a little.

Comment: Writing to a socket is equivalent to a `send()`, and `send()` makes no guarantees about the delivery of the data.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug in the man page. Saying "zero indicates nothing was written" is blatantly wrong and contrary to the specification of the `write` function which forbids ever returning zero except possibly in the (unspecified) case where the *nbyte* argument is zero: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to make `write` return zero on a socket is to ask it to write zero bytes. If there's an error on the socket you will always get `-1`.

If you want to get a "connection closed" indicator, you need to use `read` which *will* return `0` for a remotely closed connection.

Answer (score 3):

This is just how the sockets interface was written.  When you have a connected socket or pipe, you are supposed to close the transmitting end first, and then the receiving end will get EOF and can shut down.  Closing the receiving end first is "unexpected" and so it returns an error instead of returning 0.

This is important for pipes, because it allows complicated commands to finish much more quickly than they would otherwise.  For example,

```
bunzip2 < big_file.bz2 | head -n 10
```

Suppose `big_file.bz2` is huge.  Only the first part will be read, because `bunzip2` will get killed once it tries sending more data to `head`.  This makes the whole command finish much quicker, and with less CPU usage.

Sockets inherited the same behavior, with the added complication that you have to close the transmitting and receiving parts of the socket separately.

Answer (score 2):

The point to be observed is that, in TCP, when one side of the connection closes its
socket, it is actually ceasing to transmit on that socket; it sends a packet to
inform its remote peer that it will not transmit anymore through that
connection. It doesn't mean, however, that it stopped receiving too. (To
continue receiving is a local decision of the closing side; if it stops receiving, it can
lose packets transmitted by the remote peer.)

So, when you `write()` to a socket that is remotely closed, but
not locally closed, you can't know if the other end is still waiting to read
more packets, and so the TCP stack will buffer your data and try to send it. As
stated in `send()` manual page,

> No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a `send()`. Locally detected
>   errors are indicated by a return value of -1.

(When you `write()` to a socket, you are actually `send()`ing to it.)

When you `write()` a second time, though, and the remote peer has definitely
closed the socket (not only `shutdown()` writing), the local TCP stack has probably
already received a reset packet from the peer informing it about the error on
the last transmitted packet. Only then can `write()` return an error, telling
its user that this pipe is broken (`EPIPE` error code).

If the remote peer has only `shutdown()` writing, but still has the socket open,
its TCP stack will successfully receive the packet and will acknowledge the
received data back to the sender.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the whole man page then you would read, in error return values:

```
"EPIPE  fd is connected to a pipe or *socket whose reading end is closed*."
```

So, the call to write() will not return a 0 but rather -1 and errno will be set to 'EPIPE'

Comment: Then why is write() returning a value > 0 ? The ACK (or the lack of it) should let write know that it failed to transmit the data.